# Problems adding package "blue_print_pos" to project

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, package, thermal-printer

I have a flutter app that needs to use a thermal printer via bluetooth to print out a receipt. I'm trying to use the flutter plugin "[blue_print_pos](https://github.com/ankush-ppie/blue_print_pos)", but when the package is added, the project doesnt work anymore.

I want to creat a page that connects with a printer and print out something, this page is supposed to be accessed when clicking a button on the app main screen, as follows:
[Code that calls the printer widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UN03p.png)

The "PrinterWidget" class is the exact same class thatss on the main file of the package [example folder](https://github.com/ankush-ppie/blue_print_pos/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart), but for some reason the code doesnt work outside of the example project, even though I added the right dependecies.

My pubspec.yaml looks like this:
[pubspec.ymal file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwio1.png)

Afetr pasting the example class on the project I get the following errors:

../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/git/blue_print_pos-545268d0b48c9c0644b9a91b9b2c0ae415b59cbc/lib/blue_print_pos.dart:13:8: Error: Error when reading '../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_blue_plus-1.15.5/lib/gen/flutterblueplus.pb.dart': The system cannot find the specified path.

import 'package:flutter_blue_plus/gen/flutterblueplus.pb.dart' as proto;
^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/git/blue_print_pos-545268d0b48c9c0644b9a91b9b2c0ae415b59cbc/lib/blue_print_pos.dart:20:50: Error: This expression has type 'void' and can't be used.
_bluetoothIOS = flutter_blue.FlutterBluePlus.instance;
^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/git/blue_print_pos-545268d0b48c9c0644b9a91b9b2c0ae415b59cbc/lib/blue_print_pos.dart:70:25: Error: Undefined name 'BluetoothDevice_Type'.
type: proto.BluetoothDevice_Type.valueOf(selectedDevice?.type ?? 0),
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/git/blue_print_pos-545268d0b48c9c0644b9a91b9b2c0ae415b59cbc/lib/blue_print_pos.dart:67:17: Error: Method not found: 'BluetoothDevice'.
proto.BluetoothDevice(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/git/blue_print_pos-545268d0b48c9c0644b9a91b9b2c0ae415b59cbc/lib/blue_print_pos.dart:74:34: Error: The getter 'connectedDevices' isn't defined for the class 'FlutterBluePlus'.

- 'FlutterBluePlus' is from 'package:flutter_blue_plus/flutter_blue_plus.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_blue_plus-1.15.5/lib/flutter_blue_plus.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'connectedDevices'.
  await _bluetoothIOS?.connectedDevices ??
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/git/blue_print_pos-545268d0b48c9c0644b9a91b9b2c0ae415b59cbc/lib/scanner/blue_scanner.dart:29:13: Error: 'FlutterBluePlus' isn't a type.
  final FlutterBluePlus bluetoothIOS =
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/git/blue_print_pos-545268d0b48c9c0644b9a91b9b2c0ae415b59cbc/lib/scanner/blue_scanner.dart:30:11: Error: Undefined name 'FlutterBluePlus'.
  FlutterBluePlus.instance;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\FlutterSDK\flutter_windows_3.3.6-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' line: 1297
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\FlutterSDK\flutter_windows_3.3.6-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 25s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I would like to get the same results as if I was just running the example file, but on my project instead.

Comment: It seems that blue_print_pos is too old for your flutter (or dart).